# I am not able to record audio by longpress button with circularProgressBar with timer. button is disabled while launch of application

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio-recording

---Hello I'm new to objective C. I am not able to record audio while pressing buttonTapped method below listed- buttontapped is disabled while application is launched , thus i cannot record and hence I cannot play the recorded sound. kindly guide with this.

--Here is my files.

-- I have imported two files of CircularProgressBarTimer from github and imported those file in the .h file.

----This is my .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<AVAudioRecorderDelegate,AVAudioPlayerDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{
    NSTimer *timer;
    NSInteger globalTimer;
    NSInteger counter;
    NSInteger minutesLeft;
    NSInteger secondsLeft;
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
    CircularProgressTimer *progressTimerView;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonRecord;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressGesture;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CircularProgressTimer *circularProgressView;

- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender;
-(void)longPressed:(UIGestureRecognizer *)longPress;
```

And this is my .m file

```
@interface ViewController (){
    AVAudioRecorder *recorder;
    AVAudioPlayer *player;

}

@end
```

--In my viewDidLoad method i have initialise audio player, longesturerecognizer

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize buttonRecord;
@synthesize longpressGesture;
@synthesize circularProgressView;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture1 = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressed:)];
    gesture1.delegate =self;
    [gesture1 setMinimumPressDuration:(NSTimeInterval)10];
    [self.buttonRecord addGestureRecognizer:gesture1];

    //Set the audio file
    NSArray *pathComponents =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject],@"MyAudioDemo.m4a", nil];
    NSURL *outputFileURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];


    //Set the audio Session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    //Define the recorder Setting
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
    //Initiate and prepare the recorder
    recorder=[[AVAudioRecorder alloc]initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];
    recorder.delegate=self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled =YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    //Disable play button when application launches
    [buttonRecord setEnabled:NO];
}
```

---And i have aldo define the circularprogress bar method about the size allocation.

```
- (void)drawCircularProgressBarWithMinutesLeft:(NSInteger)minutes secondsLeft:(NSInteger)seconds
{
    // Removing unused view to prevent them from stacking up
    for (id subView in [self.view subviews]) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[CircularProgressTimer class]]) {
            [subView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    // Init our view and set current circular progress bar value
    CGRect progressBarFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 180);
    progressTimerView = [[CircularProgressTimer alloc] initWithFrame:progressBarFrame];
    [progressTimerView setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 210)];
    [progressTimerView setPercent:seconds];
    if (/*minutes == 0 &&*/ seconds == 0) {
        [progressTimerView setInstanceColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }

    // Here, setting the minutes left before adding it to the parent view
    //[progressTimerView setMinutesLeft:minutesLeft];
    [progressTimerView setSecondsLeft:secondsLeft];
    [self.view addSubview:progressTimerView];
    progressTimerView = nil;
}

- (void)startTimer
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(updateCircularProgressBar)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateCircularProgressBar
{
    // Values to be passed on to Circular Progress Bar
    if (globalTimer > 0 && globalTimer <= 1200) {
        globalTimer--;
        // minutesLeft = globalTimer / 60;
        secondsLeft = globalTimer % 43;

        [self drawCircularProgressBarWithMinutesLeft:minutesLeft secondsLeft:secondsLeft];
        NSLog(@"Time left:%02ld", (long)secondsLeft);
    } else {
        [self drawCircularProgressBarWithMinutesLeft:0 secondsLeft:0];
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}



- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    switch (event.subtype) {
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
            [self.circularProgressView pause];
                       break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
            [self.circularProgressView play];

                    default:
            break;
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}
```

----I know I have done wrong code in buttonRecord event. but when I debug the application the button is disabled and cannot be pressed. Please guide me with this, that would be appreciated.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    if (player.playing) {
        [player stop];
    }

    if (!recorder.recording) {
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [session setActive:YES error:nil];

        // Start recording
        [recorder record];
        [buttonRecord setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } else {

        // Pause recording
        [recorder pause];
        [buttonRecord setTitle:@"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    //[stopButton setEnabled:YES];
    [_playButton setEnabled:NO];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(updateCircularProgressBar)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];

    NSLog(@"playTapped");
    if (!recorder.recording) {
        player =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
        //[player setDelegate:self];
        [buttonRecord setEnabled:YES];
        [recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval)10];
        [recorder record];


}
}
- (IBAction)playbuttontTapped:(id)sender {
    if (!recorder.recording){
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
        [player setDelegate:self];
        [player play];
    }}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) That's a lot of code ... try to reproduce the problem by creating a [mcve]

Comment: My problem is I am not able to record audio because it is showing disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line in your `viewDidLoad` is causing your record button to be dissabled, why have yo added this     `[buttonRecord setEnabled:NO];`

You may try changing it to     `[buttonRecord setEnabled:YES];` or removing that line completely

Comment: ok that is done, button is enabled now, but I'm not able to record audio and play it further .. :-?

Comment: can you help me further ?

Comment: @MihirB ,you said you are not able to record because the button is dissabled,please mark this answer as correct, if it solved your question.  also should take that up as a new question, and also remove, a lot of unwanted Code you have added in your question. and  Il try to look more closely at your code and try to reply if possible